# Combine these 2 SQL queries that inserts the primary key as a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query #1:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
     WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
       AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM' 
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AS pk
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM.*, hash_key
FROM
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (HASHBYTES('md5', CONCAT('', DW_RLT_SRC_ID)))) hk (hash_key)
```

The first query identifies the primary key for whatever table I am using. I am going to replace

```
AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM'  
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

with a placeholder that runs through all the table names in my python code.

The second query creates a `hash_key` value based off the primary keys for each table which are obviously going to be different for each table. This is why I want to automate what primary key columns are being used for each table and then create a hash_key from the primary keys used for each table. This data will then get inserted into the staging tables.

That's the logic I am going for. I am stuck on how to combine these 2 queries so that `pk` is used as a variable that stores whatever the primary key is for that table and then I want to use `pk` in place of `DW_RLT_SRC_ID` which is the hard-coded primary key. I am not sure how to combine them, I tried UNION but it doesn't work.

My data looks like this:

| DW_RLT_SRC_ID | RLT_SRC_CDE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CIS |
| 2 | LN |

After I run Query #2, this is what it looks like and this is what I want to insert into my staging table:

| DW_RLT_SRC_ID | RLT_SRC_CDE | hash_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CIS | ÄÊB8 ¹# ÌP ou |
| 2 | LN | È r L/co Ì , |

I am trying to store the primary key as a variable in Query #1 so I can use whatever the primary key is in Query #2 instead of hardcoding the primary key in Query #2. This is so I can use it for other tables as well. Right now my code works for just 1 table but if I want to automate this process for all 2500 tables, I need to find the primary key for each table (which is done in Query #1) and then insert that primary key in Query #2.

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM.*, hash_key
FROM
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (HASHBYTES('md5', CONCAT('', pk)))) hk (hash_key)
```

where the primary key is taken from Query #1 and just inserted into Query #2

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results so we can visualise the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you are running these queries in code, just get the results of the first query and use them as parameters to the second query? If you want to do it in SQL you're going to have to write a loop in dynamic SQL which isn't fund.

Comment: Just a quick question - **Why do you want to do this?** This seems to me like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ZoharPeled people already wasted time trying to deschiffer the purpose of this in the previous question. I'm guessing the OP doesn't know himself but wants to continue driving off that cliff

Comment: @siggemannen I don't remember reading the previous question you're referring to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I have understood your question: Run your first query as a sub query of the second, then pull the key.

```
SELECT
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM.*, hash_key
FROM
    TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
       AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM' 
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
) AS pk
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (HASHBYTES('md5', CONCAT('', pk.COLUMN_NAME)))) hk (hash_key)
```

Could add it to stored procedure and then pass in the schema and table.

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname = 'TB_CI_DZJ_C2_RLT_SRC_DIM'
DECLARE @tableSchema sysname = 'dbo'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) ='SELECT
    target.*, hash_key
FROM
    '+QUOTENAME(@tableSchema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+' AS target
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
     WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1
       AND TABLE_NAME = '''+@tableName+''' 
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '''+@tableSchema+'''
) pk
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (HASHBYTES(''md5'', CONCAT('''', pk.COLUMN_NAME)))) hk (hash_key)'
    
    exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Heads up: when using dynamic SQL, take extra care about parameters you're passing. Always use `QUOTENAME` to wrap identifiers and parameterize whatever you can. Also, don't use `nvarchar(128)` for identifiers, use `sysname` instead.
For some more info, check out my blog post entitled [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/)

Comment: Updated, had the schema and table reversed too. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE shows TABLE_SCHEMA as nvarchar -- changed both though as, yes, schema is a sysname (at least normally) -- guess KEY_COLUMN_USAGE is just the view.